# Unable to activate bundle in Sling that consumes SOAP service using JAX WS RI

Tags: web-services, maven, soap, osgi, sling

First the requirement:

I need to write code that consumes a SOAP service and build it as an OSGi bundle that can be deployed in Apache Sling. The build is done using Maven 3.0.3

What I have done so far:

I created a maven module and used this for generating SOAP client classes: https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html. I had to remove the plugin dependency jaxws-tools version 2.2.5 as it was not supporting the -encoding parameter to wsimport. Removing it automatically downloads version 2.2.8 and it works fine as it is a dependency for the POM.

Next, I changed the package type to bundle and included maven-bundle-plugin and maven-scr-plugin to package the generated code as a OSGi bundle and built it using Maven

Finally I deployed it to Sling running locally as a standalone application.

Following are the issues I faced in the given order:

1. javax.jws package unresolved - I included this as a private-package under configurations for the maven-bundle-plugin
2. Similar packages that were unresolved were added which includes:

   javax.xml.ws
   javax.xml.ws.handler
   javax.xml.ws.spi
   javax.xml.ws.spi.http
   javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing

   1. After adding these to the private-package, I started getting this error:
      (javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found) javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Root Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found by org.apache.felix.http.jetty

This is where I hit a roadblock which I am not able to move past.

What I have tried so far to fix this based on numerous answers on google

1. tried to include this line in the sling.properties file:
   sling.bootdelegation.com.sun=com.sun.*
2. Tried adding this line
   sling.system.packages.simple=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
3. Tried adding this line
   sling.bootdelegation.class.com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi
4. Tried adding all the packages mentioned earlier to the org.osgi.framework.system.packages property as well as to the jre-1.6 property
   After doing this, I can see that these packages are now being exposed by the system bundle. But only the javax.jws is showing as resolved. All other bundles still show as unresolved.
5. Tried all possible combinations of export-packages.
6. Even tried to remove unresolved packages as suggested by some posts

I am using Maven 3.0.3, JDK 1.6.0_43, Apache Sling org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar 2.4.0 all of which is running on my Mac Book Pro with OSX 10.8.5
Here is my POM snippet that is relevant to this question. If more information is needed I can provide the same as well

```
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Private-Package>
                            <!--javax.jws,-->
                            javax.xml.ws,
                            javax.xml.ws.handler,
                            javax.xml.ws.spi,
                            javax.xml.ws.spi.http,
                            javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing
                        </Private-Package>
                        <!--
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            !javax.xml.ws,*
                        </Import-Package>
                        -->
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- The name of your generated source package -->
                    <packageName>com.mycompany.mypackage</packageName>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>http://localhost/mysoapservice?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2.7</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2.9</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Waiting for a response in anticipation.